# Unable to resolve class grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured - Grails 2.3.11

Tags: grails

I have a project in the old grails, and I'm trying to upgrade it to the new version of grails 2.3.11, but this one giving error with the import for the mult tenant plugin, this is an example of an error:

```
D:\~.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured
 @ line 5, column 1.
   import grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured
   ^

D:\~.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured
 @ line 3, column 1.
   import grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured
```

This is my buildConfig:

```
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // uncomment to disable ehcache
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    repositories {
        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        // uncomment the below to enable remote dependency resolution
        // from public Maven repositories
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }
    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.

        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.13'
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.gagravarr/vorbis-java-core
        compile group: 'org.gagravarr', name: 'vorbis-java-core', version: '0.8'

    }
    plugins {
        //build ":tomcat:7.0.52.1"
        build ":tomcat:7.0.70"
        runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.9"

        compile ':scaffolding:2.0.3'

        runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
        compile ':cache:1.1.1'

        runtime ':resources:1.2.8'

        compile ":cache-headers:1.1.5"
        runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
        runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
        runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"

        // framework dependencies
        compile ":mail:1.0.1"
        compile ":fields:1.4"
        compile ":runtime-logging:0.4"
        compile ":burning-image:0.5.1"
        compile ":twitter-bootstrap:2.3.2"
        compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"
        compile ":spring-security-rest:1.4.0.RC5"/*, {
            excludes: 'spring-security-core'
        }*/

        // events to implement app hooks
        compile ":platform-core:1.0.RC6"

        // Para fazer upload de imagens
        compile ":attachmentable:0.3.0"

        // calendários para campos do tipo Date
        compile ":calendar:1.2.1"

        // exportar dados para Excel
        compile ":excel-export:0.1.9", {
            excludes: 'xerces'
        }

        // Jasper Reports
        compile ":jasper:1.11.0"

        // Export CSV
        compile ":csv:0.3.1"

        // Tests
        test ":cucumber:0.6.2"

        // Profiling
        compile ":profiler:0.5"

        //webservice SOAP
        compile ":cxf:1.1.4"
        compile ":cxf-client:2.0.3"

        //cron job
        compile ":quartz:1.0.2"

        compile ":ws-client:1.0"
        compile ":multi-tenant-single-db:0.8.3"

        //compile ":falcone-util:1.0"
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this error? Or what do I have to change in my buildconfig to solve, maybe a newer plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check docs for [grails-spring-security-core](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/2.0.x/guide/requestMappings.html#securedAnnotations) you could find that mentioned, problematic class: `grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured` is 
now used as `grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured`.

So if you are using it anywhere it project, you should update import statement.